# Default headers not applying to request

Tags: guzzle, guzzle6

New to guzzle.  I am trying to use it contact a REST endpoint.  Sending the request via curl or using something like postman app for chrome it returns the expected JSON response.  Sending it using guzzle below is returning a 404 error similar to what would be returned if I hit the URL without the headers inlcuded.

Why are the headers not making it into this request?

```
 // Get extra detail for the object
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
   'base_uri' => env('OPENIDM_URL'),
   'headers' => [
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     'X-OpenIDM-Username' => env('OPENIDM_USER'),
     'X-OpenIDM-Password' => env('OPENIDM_PASS'),
     'Authorization' => 'Basic Og=='
   ]
 ]);

 $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $attributes['sourceobjectid']);
 $res = $client->send($request);
```

I have dumped the content of the client and request objects.  They look as follows:

```
Client {#181 ▼
  -config: array:8 [▼
    "base_uri" => Uri {#188 ▼
      -scheme: "https"
      -userInfo: ""
      -host: "my.url.here.com"
      -port: null
      -path: "/openidm"
      -query: ""
      -fragment: ""
    }
    "headers" => array:5 [▼
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
      "X-OpenIDM-Username" => "myuser"
      "X-OpenIDM-Password" => "mypass"
      "Authorization" => "Basic Og=="
      "User-Agent" => "GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.38.0 PHP/5.6.26-0+deb8u1"
    ]
    "handler" => HandlerStack {#169 ▶}
    "allow_redirects" => array:5 [▶]
    "http_errors" => true
    "decode_content" => true
    "verify" => true
    "cookies" => false
  ]
}
Request {#189 ▼
  -method: "GET"
  -requestTarget: null
  -uri: Uri {#190 ▼
    -scheme: ""
    -userInfo: ""
    -host: ""
    -port: null
    -path: "managed/user/eb758aab-7896-4196-8989-ba7f97a7e962"
    -query: ""
    -fragment: ""
  }
  -headers: []
  -headerNames: []
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: null
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It can be done with using HandlerStack. Please take a look in Guzzle docs - http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html#handlerstack

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the request object yourself, Guzzle won't apply configurations to it.

You either have to use the convenience HTTP methods (get, put, etc) called from the client or use a custom middleware.

The first one is easier, the second one gives you more power, but responsibility too.